# Adding variables in query the right way

Tags: php

Why do this..

```
$fruit_type = "banana";
mysql_real_escape_string($fruit_type);

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fruit = " . $fruit_type . ";
```

when you can do this..

```
$fruit_type = "banana";
mysql_real_escape_string($fruit_type);

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fruit = $fruit_type;
```

I know that integers should be encapsulated in single quotes but is it fine to add a variable that contains a string directly?

Comment: where do you know that integers should be encapsulated in single quotes?

Comment: @Unreason they are not? Most queries with vars that = numbers don't work unless in single quotes. From my experience.

Comment: @Noob: Erm, you must not have much experience. Single quotes enclose strings, not numbers. It doesn't make sense to enclose numbers within quotes, even if it does work.

Comment: @Vincent hence my username lol. I must be confusing the two.

Comment: @Vincent actually there are instances when I encapsulate integers in single quotes otherwise the query doesn't work..

Comment: @Noob: I'd really like to know which ones. Unless you use a string type (varchar/text), there's no need to use quotes.

Comment: @Vincent for example I have `$category_id = $row["category_id"]; //a numeric data type` and in a query for some reason I use `"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id = '$category_id'..."`

Comment: @Noob: First of all, this looks like a query in a loop, you should never do that but do a `INNER JOIN` query instead. Then, if `$row["category_id"]` really is an integer, you don't have to use quotes. It works, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Ahh I see. I recall a time when I absolutely had to use the quotes. Hmmmmmmm..... maybe it was in a js statement. It just stuck with me since I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a string directly, without quotes (and escaped quotes within the value) will *not* work if that is your question.

The following *will* work with integers, provided you are matching on an number field, but it will *not* work with strings:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fruit = $fruit_type";
```

To match strings, you must enclose them within single quotes, and escape single quotes occurring within the value. The following will not escape quotes contained within the passed variable:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fruit = '$fruit_type'";
```

At the very least, you should do this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fruit = " . mysql_real_escape_string($fruit_type);
```

And at the first opportunity, read about these:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

Typically, no. The reason is just this:

```
$fruit_type = "; DELETE FROM posts;";
```

There's nothing inherently wrong with the syntax, it's your approach in general. You want to make sure that all user input strings are escaped.

Comment: SQL injection can do really really nasty things. See http://xkcd.com/327/ (for an example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you referring to `mysql_real_escape_string` on the `$fruit_type` variable? I didn't add that because I thought it's self-evident. I'm more interested in the query. Maybe I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Disagree with this answer. The way you put a string variable into a string literal doesn't necessarily assume anything about whether it's escaped or not. In fact, I would argue a good system has centralized escaping rather than doing it all inline.

Comment: @Renesis: Right, that's why I put "There's nothing inherently wrong with the syntax."

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the quotes for the string.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fruit = '$fruit_type';
```

Also, its a good practice to use bind variables in SQL in order to avoid DB query parsing

Answer (score -2):

To late but it will help others 
`

```
$table ="table_Name";
$idx="value";
$sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE row_name= '$idx'";
```

`
execute your query .

Comment: SQL injection hole